# Run a remote script using shebang in Linux

Tags: linux, curl, wget, cloud-init

I know to run a remote script, we can use

`curl -s <remote-script-url> | python` or `wget -O - <remote-script-url> | bash`

But, instead of specifying the interpreter explicitly, can we run the script using shebang.

My use case is, the scripts will be from trusted sources - may be python or bash and I run it from EC2 User data.
If the above is not possible, is it a way to achieve the same using cloud-config (script will be in s3)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Download it to a file, mark the file as executable and run it. I'm sure you can do it as a 1 liner if you try hard enough...

Comment: Thanks John, that is what I'm doing right now.. I'm taking care of deleting the script after executing it. I don't want users to execute again after the instance is up.